# Show Telephone and Company on Registration form in magento1.9 after showing get validation errors?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, registration, address-attribute

I want to show Telephone and Company field on my Registration form, that is already achieved.
For that I just put the fields out from this condition:

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
```

in register.phtml

> (/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml).

After this the fields are visible but the issue is, **when I submit my form it shows error for other address fields like city, street, zip etc, which is not on my registration form**.

Comment: You have to create customer attribute to achieve this.

Comment: @SoumikRana, This field is already present in magento and it is easy to display it but the issue is saving and the other fields validations that are showing when I set this <?php $this->getShowAddressFields(true) ?>